# Symfony2 Web Profiler disappeared ajax calling but invalid response in google chrome only

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, symfony, profiler

Im just working on a project with symfony2 and yesterday i started to design it.
Not i just noticed that the web profiler is not visible.

I tried everything! it is active in the config_dev, body tags are opened and closed well. The JS Code is loaded just before </body> and the /_wdt request is called, but heres the response:

[image: error]

now just calling myself this url returns the right response. in this case, the toolbar is shown.

**I just tried the same with safari and firefox and everything worked well?! So only it is failing with chrome (even in ikognito mode with no plugin).**

so it must have something to do with what? i dunno..
and since this time [TinymceBundle](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) not works well also. Even if the js code is loaded my textarea with the .tinymce class is not a Tinymce Textarea, Some Js code errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Zend Server CE as Environment. Just stopping and Starting the Server fixed the bug?!